# AWS Cognito - Setting default account name in MFA authenticator apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

I have set up TOTP MFA for my app with AWS Cognito.

The account name in the authenticator app is being set to 'AWSCognito' as you can see in the screenshot below.

I was not able to find a setting to set this to, say, 'XYZ'
Is there a way to set default value for this?

[image: Authenticator app]

Comment: Seem like no way to custom the name on the AWS Cognito. Did you add MFA for a new user via the Scan QR code? IMO, you can add a new MFA by manually inputting the secret code, then it allows you to custom the name.

Comment: User scans the QR code, enters secret code and MFA is set up for them, they can then edit the name in their apps, however I am looking for a way to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the account name by changing the issuer name in the string that goes into the QR code. Here's the string I was generating

```
`otpauth://totp/AWSCognito:${email}?secret=${code}&issuer=https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/`
```

Replace 'AWSCognito' with your app name.

Comment: where should I use this code? i have same issue